# Install FBExport in the CentOS 7 terminal

Tags: linux, firebird, fbexport

I need to export data from Firebird to a CSV file. When I used Google, I found the FBExport tool. I need to install this tool on my CentOS 6 machine. I am using CentOS Server. How do I install FBExport in my terminal? Is there any proper documentation for this?

I'm using CentOS 6.

I have unzipped the file and after that I couldn't find any installation file. I am a Linux beginner please help me.

After unzipped the file , i tried to run the fbexport file, but the result is 'command not found'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a folder in  your terminal and execute the below code

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/mariuz/fbexport`
   ```
2. open Fbexport folder and execute the below command

   ```
   make all;
   ```
3. If you face any error like g++ command not found then run the below command

   ```
   yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
   ```
4. Again execute the command `make all`, if you face any error like ***cannot find - lfbclient*** then do the following commands

   ```
   sudo -i;
   cd /lib64
   ln -s  libfbclient.so.2.5.9 libfbclient.so
   ```
5. Execute `make all` command.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Makefile to install. If you have `make` installed, you can use:

```bash
make install
```

Alternatively, you should ensure that the `exe/fbexport` file is executable and run that.

That said, it was compiled in 2009, so possible it will not run as-is, and you may need to compile from source yourself. That means installing GCC in addition to make. You'll also need to have the Firebird client libraries installed. Then use:

```bash
make clean
make all
make install
```

NOTE: I haven't actually followed these steps myself, and I don't know if the code is still compilable on recent compiler versions.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark....As you said I have tried to install... now I got new error /bin/ld: cannot find -lfbclient
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ......should I  download file? or do something else? ..

Comment: I don't normally work on Linux, but you need to have libfbclient.so on the library path, and may you need to install the "development" files for Firebird (at least, I think that is how some distributions call them).

Comment: I have added below code  $lib64>ln -s  libfbclient.so.2.5.9 libfbclient.so  now its working properly